# TeamCity запуск 2 bat файла одновременно

Tags: bat, teamcity

Всем привет! Подскажите можно ли в TeamCity запустить одновременно два исполняемых файла проекта, на одной джобе, под 1 агентом (пример: указать путь на bat файл, который вызывает еще 2 bat файла).

Comment: Из одного .BAT нельзя запустить ОДНОВРЕМЕННО два других. Но можно запустить параллельно два CMD.EXE, каждый из которых выполнит свой .BAT. `start "" cmd.exe /c file.bat` два раза.

Comment: я думаю, это то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: @Akina и подскажите, если не трудно, в `""` какие значения должны быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, запустите `start /?` и посмотрИте самостоятельно, зачем кавычки и что в них пишется. Заодно посмОтрите и остальные доступные параметры команды.